# AVAssetExportSession gives me AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800

Tags: swift, avfoundation, ios13, avassetexportsession

I am facing the same issues in ios 13.3 in real device it is working in ios 13.2 simulator but gives below error.

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could
>   not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error
>   occurred (-17508), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be
>   completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x2816d11d0 {Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-17508 "(null)"}}

Here is my code I want to convert .mov file to mp4.

```
class func encodeVideo(at videoURL: String, completionHandler: ((URL?, Error?) -> Void)?)  {  
    let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: videoURL), options: nil)  

    let startDate = Date()  

    //Create Export session  
    guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: avAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough) else {  
        completionHandler?(nil, nil)  
        return  
    }  

    //Creating temp path to save the converted video  
    let filename = "Video_\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).mp4"  
      // Below Folder Path used tor getting directory path  
    let strfilePath = (FolderPath.temporaryDirectory.getDirectoryPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent(filename)  
    let filePath = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: strfilePath)  

    //Check if the file already exists then remove the previous file  
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) {  
        do {  
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: filePath)  
        } catch {  
            completionHandler?(nil, error)  
        }  
    }  

    exportSession.outputURL = filePath  
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4  
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true  
    let start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, preferredTimescale: 0)  
    let range = CMTimeRangeMake(start: start, duration: avAsset.duration)  
    exportSession.timeRange = range  

    exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {() -> Void in  
        switch exportSession.status {  
        case .failed:  
            print(exportSession.error ?? "NO ERROR")  
            completionHandler?(nil, exportSession.error)  
        case .cancelled:  
            print("Export canceled")  
            completionHandler?(nil, nil)  
        case .completed:  
            //Video conversion finished  
            let endDate = Date()  

            let time = endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)  
            print(time)  
            print("Successful!")  
            print(exportSession.outputURL ?? "NO OUTPUT URL")  
            completionHandler?(exportSession.outputURL, nil)  

            default: break  
        }  

    })  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solve my issues by using AVMutableComposition not directly using AVURL asset. I adding audio and video track in AVMutableComposition.

Answer (score 2):

```
let strfilePath = (FolderPath.temporaryDirectory.getDirectoryPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent(filename)
```

you cannot store in that folder directly, but you need to store your file in a subfolder, e.g. like this:

```
let documentDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as NSURL

let strfilePath = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("Subfolder/filename.mp4") as URL
```

Further you can read this  [article](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121902)

Comment: This is not a case still I got same issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to convert .mov to .mp4

```
  var outputURL: URL!

   func exportVideo(key:String, inputurl: URL, presetName: String, outputFileType: AVFileType = .mp4, fileExtension: String = "mp4", then completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {

        let asset = AVAsset(url: inputurl)

        outputURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(key)

        if let session = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: presetName) {
            session.outputURL = outputURL
            session.outputFileType = outputFileType

            session.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
            session.exportAsynchronously {
                switch session.status {
                case .completed:
                    completion(self.outputURL)
                case .cancelled:
                    debugPrint("Video export cancelled.")
                    completion(nil)
                case .failed:
                    let errorMessage = session.error?.localizedDescription ?? "n/a"
                    debugPrint("Video export failed with error: \(errorMessage)")
                    completion(nil)
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
```

And then I call this function to get the output URL of the converted file and use it

```
exportVideo(key: key, inputurl: path, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality, outputFileType: .mp4, fileExtension: "mp4") { (outputURL) in 

    // do whatever with the file here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stuck in this frustrating error. Use a AVmutablecomposition as export asset.

Sample code for trimming a video:

```
let manager = FileManager.default
        guard let documentDirectory = try?  manager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)  else { print("TRIM Failed to access directory")
            return}
     
       
        
        
        let mediaType = "mp4"
        if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie as String || mediaType == "mp4" as String {
               let asset = AVAsset(url:videoURL!)
            let length = Float(asset.duration.value) / Float(asset.duration.timescale)
               print("TRIM video length: \(length) seconds")
            
       
            let composition = AVMutableComposition()
            let audioTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!
            let videoTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!
            
     
            var outURL_speed=documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("output")
            var outputURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("output")
            
                    do {
                        
                     
                        try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(start: self.startTime, end: self.endTime), of: asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)[0], at: CMTime.zero)
                        try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(start: self.startTime, end: self.endTime), of: asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0], at: CMTime.zero)
                     
                        try manager.createDirectory(at: outputURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                        outputURL = outputURL.appendingPathComponent("preVideo-\(self.postID).\(mediaType)")
                        outURL_speed = outURL_speed.appendingPathComponent("Video-\(self.postID).\(mediaType)")
                        print("TRIM output dir: \(outputURL)")
                    }catch let error {
                        print(error)
                    }

            _ = try? manager.removeItem(at: outputURL)
            
            
        
            
            guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {return}
            
            exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
            exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
            exportSession.outputFileType = .mp4
            let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: self.startTime, end: self.endTime)
            exportSession.timeRange = timeRange
            
            exportSession.exportAsynchronously{
                switch exportSession.status {
                case .completed:
                    print("TRIM exported at \(outputURL)")
                    self.changeSpeed(url: outputURL,outUrl:outURL_speed)
                case .failed:
                    print("TRIM failed \(exportSession.error)")

                case .cancelled:
                    print("TRIM cancelled \(exportSession.error)")

                default: break
                }
            }
```

Comment: For the record, I've seen this error in the wild (very rarely) and we do use AVMutableComposition to do our exports.